# Pray as if he sees you vs. Pray as if he is seeing you

Tags: grammar, tenses

When we want to write or say about something general as in the following, which sentence makes more sense over the other? And what could be the differences?

> When you pray to God, pray in a way as though he **watches/sees** you.
> When you pray to God, pray in a way as though he **is watching/seeing** you.
>
> When you pray to God, pray as if you **see** him.
> When you pray to God, pray as if you **are seeing** him.

Comment: do you mean "watch/see"?

Comment: The constructions in your title make a lot more sense than the sentences in the actual question text. In the title *he* is seeing you.  In the question *you* are seeing him.  'Him seeing you' seems to match a wider range of accepted religious beliefs I think.

Comment: Please edit your Q. per above comments.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5904)?

Comment: related: [I have always been confused between using watch or see a movie](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6183/i-have-always-been-confused-between-using-watch-or-see-a-movie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*See* is one of the sensory verbs that is generally not used in the continuous form. So in each of the following pairs the first is grammatical and the second is not:

- I see a cat. I am seeing a cat.
- I hear the phone. I am hearing the phone.
- I smelled cheese. I was smelling cheese.

Commonly, such sensory verbs are used with *can*: *I can see a cat*, *I could smell cheese*, etc.

*Watch* can take with both verb forms, with the continuous form used for actions in progress.

On this basis, your sentences read best as:

- When you pray to God, pray (in a way) as though he can see you.
- When you pray to God, pray in a way as though he is watching you.
- When you pray to God, pray as if you can see him.
- When you pray to God, pray as if you are watching him.

Comment: I tend to use *...as if/though ... were...* (not *was*) exclusively myself. *“Pray as if he **were** watching.”*

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning (for the OP) that 'seeing' can be used in the sense of visiting ~ "I am seeing the doctor in the morning", and 'smelling' can be used for the act of testing the smell of something ~ "she was smelling different perfumes at the counter".

Comment: I had to chuckle at _I could smell cheese_.  Who cut the cheese?